# How to make jQuery add css dynamaically on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am currently horizontally and vertically aligning a div. Its width and height varies depending on its childrens sizes. I am using this code to do that successfully.

```
$('.tiles-wrapper').css({top:'50%',left:'50%',margin:'-'+($('.tiles-wrapper').height() / 2)+'px 0 0 -'+($('.tiles-wrapper').width() / 2)+'px'});
```

I would like it to continue to work when the page window is resized as it currently does not. Any help would be great. Thanks

With your help I have got it working. Is this the best way to lay the code out?

```
<script>
    $('.tiles-wrapper').css({top:'50%',left:'50%',margin:'-'+($('.tiles-wrapper').height() / 2)+'px 0 0 -'+($('.tiles-wrapper').width() / 2)+'px'});

    $(window).resize(function() {
        $('.tiles-wrapper').css({top:'50%',left:'50%',margin:'-'+($('.tiles-wrapper').height() / 2)+'px 0 0 -'+($('.tiles-wrapper').width() / 2)+'px'});
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the [jQuery window resize](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) function, `$(window).resize(function() {} );` ? Anything in this function is called whenever the page is resized:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('.tiles-wrapper').css({top:'50%',left:'50%',margin:'-'+($('.tiles-wrapper').height() / 2)+'px 0 0 -'+($('.tiles-wrapper').width() / 2)+'px'});

});
```

You can also call this function manually via `$(window).resize();`

Comment: Yes I did try that but then it only does it when the window is resized. I need it to do it initially and then on window resize too. Is that possible?

Comment: Updated my answer... you can call it anytime via `$(window).resize();`